# Get length of Columns using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)

Tags: sql-server, smo

I'm writing T4 templates to generate CRUD stored procs etc

I am looping through the columns of a table using SMO:

```
For Each column As Column In table.Columns
    WriteLine("@" & column.Name & " " & column.DataType.Name & ", ")
Next
```

My question is simply how do I find the Length of a varchar column? There doesn't appear to be any Length / MaxLength etc property on the column.

I'm using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.column_members.aspx as a reference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Column` type has a property called `DataType` which contains these bits of information you're looking for:

```
int maxLen = column.DataType.MaximumLength;
int maxPrecision = column.DataType.NumericPrecision;
int numericScale = column.DataType.NumericScale;
```

and so on. Not all fields are filled for every type, obviously - numeric scale on a VARCHAR doesn't make sense....

Check out the [MSDN docs on precision, scale and max length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx). The main sentence is this:

> Precision is the number of digits in a
>   number. Scale is the number of digits
>   to the right of the decimal point in a
>   number. For example, the number 123.45
>   has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

So a `DECIMAL(12,4)`  has a **precision** of 12 digits (total), of which 4 are after the decimal point (the **scale**) and thus 8 digits are before the decimal point.

But those should be the fields you're looking for, right?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
column.Properties["Length"].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get all the field properties:

```
<#= propertyType #>
<#=col.DataType.MaximumLength#>
<#=col.Nullable?"?":""#>
```